# Extract a word between a pattern in linux

Tags: regex, unix, sed, grep, text-extraction

I have a file with multiple lines and i would like to extract the word in between `-d` and `-e`, if the file has more than one occurrences, the first one is fine.

example:

if the contents of the file is as below

```
someText -d wordToExtract -e someOtherWord and so on, -d Hello -e
```

I want to extract `wordToExtract` which is the first occurrence.

I tried using `grep` and `sed` commands but couldnt achieve it because i am new to `unix`. Any help is appreciated.

one of the example i tried

```
grep -o -P '(?<=\\-d).*(?=\\-i)' fileName
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your input text:

```
x='someText -d wordToExtract -e someOtherWord and so on, -d Hello -e'
```

This awk will extract first match:

```
awk -F '-(d|e) *' '{print $2}' <<< "$x"
wordToExtract
```

This grep should work to extract all matches strings between `-d` and `-e`:

```
grep -oP '\-d *\K(.*?)(?= *-e)' <<< "$x"
wordToExtract
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). I prefer it to [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) because has non-greddy quantifiers and to [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) because it can avoid multiple matches per line:

```
perl -ne 'm/-d\s*(.*?)\s*-e/ && print "$1\n"' infile
```

It yields:

```
wordToExtract
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regexp:

```
-d(.*?)-e
```

Obviously escaping is necessary, and also the switches -o -P